# HTML, javascript - Displaying input value to a label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, label

I want to display the value of an `<input>` to a label or something like that, by using onkeyup so it's real time. But can only do it by using a second input instead of the label but I just want to display the value.

This is my Javascript function:

```
function copyTo(obj) {
    document.getElementById("utmatning").value = obj.value
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<label>E-post:</label>
<input id="inmatning" type="text" onkeyup="copyTo(this)" placeholder="Skriv in e-post…">
<span>Vår återkoppling kommer att skickas till:</span>
<br>
<label id="utmatning"></label>
```

Comment: u need to use "innerHTML" if u want content from <label id="utmatning"></label>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `textContent` for label

```
 document.getElementById("utmatning").textContent = obj.value
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/kcK74/)

Comment: OP added the jQuery tag as well

Answer (score 0):

You can also call the keyup function of jquery and update the label on every keystroke:
http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$( "#inmatning" ).keyup(function() {
    $("#utmatning").text($("#inmatning").val());
});
```

Or

```
$( "#inmatning" ).keyup(function() {
    $("#utmatning").html($("#inmatning").val());
});
```

both should work

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this also if you are seeking short method use jquery :

    $( "#inmatning" ).keyup(function() {
        $("#utmatning").text($(this).val());
    });

    or use 
    $( "#inmatning" ).keyup(function() {
        $("#utmatning").text($("#inmatning").val());
    });

but you are using function then you can also use:

function copyTo(that){
 $("#utmatning").text($(that).val());
}
```